# resolving a subdomain with dnscrypt-proxy returns an IP address but claims that the domain does not exist

Tags: dns, dnscrypt

I am using `dnscrpyt-proxy` as a local stub for using DoH. Resolving subdomains claims that they "probably" don't exist or are blocked by the proxy but the IP returned is correct.
I am not sure if this is to be expected or indicative of some issue.

**How is the output for below two examples to be interpreted?**

```bsh
generic@motorbrot:/etc$ /opt/dnscrypt-proxy-2.0.44/dnscrypt-proxy -resolve docs.google.com
Resolving [docs.google.com]

Domain exists:  probably not, or blocked by the proxy
Canonical name: docs.google.com.
IP addresses:   216.58.200.14, 2404:6800:4005:805::200e
TXT records:    google-site-verification=Ea9DtyEruwUPQhZm6VkAeu8Ww7RdLyfV-ounIdQlkuY
Resolver IP:    104.238.170.136 (104.238.170.136.vultr.com.)

generic@motorbrot:/etc$ /opt/dnscrypt-proxy-2.0.44/dnscrypt-proxy -resolve drive.google.com
Resolving [drive.google.com]

Domain exists:  probably not, or blocked by the proxy
Canonical name: drive.google.com.
IP addresses:   172.217.16.142, 2404:6800:4005:802::200e
TXT records:    google-site-verification=pGMCXdTAsGW_L3o1ks9eToJ4g1R-l3r8TcXdkcA9RqY
Resolver IP:    185.95.216.116
```

```bsh
generic@motorbrot:/etc$ /opt/dnscrypt-proxy-2.0.44/dnscrypt-proxy -resolve eric.mink.li
Resolving [eric.mink.li]

Domain exists:  probably not, or blocked by the proxy
Canonical name: eric.mink.li.
IP addresses:   80.74.154.155
TXT records:    -
Resolver IP:    185.95.216.116

generic@motorbrot:/etc$ /opt/dnscrypt-proxy-2.0.44/dnscrypt-proxy -resolve mink.li
Resolving [mink.li]

Domain exists:  yes, 3 name servers found
Canonical name: mink.li.
IP addresses:   80.74.154.155
TXT records:    -
Resolver IP:    185.95.216.116
```

It's also interesting to note that not all subdomains exhibit this behaviour. For example this other website:

```bsh
generic@motorbrot:/etc$ /opt/dnscrypt-proxy-2.0.44/dnscrypt-proxy -resolve eric.mink.com
Resolving [eric.mink.com]

Domain exists:  yes, 2 name servers found
Canonical name: eric.mink.com.
IP addresses:   69.172.201.153
TXT records:    -
Resolver IP:    185.95.216.116
```

These subdomains are all accessible in the browser (the `eric.mink.com` example is a redirect though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted, `Domain exists:  probably not, or blocked by the proxy` is a little bit confusing.

It actually means that a query for that name returned a response that doesn't include any name servers.

A query for an actual domain (not host name) such as `google.com` would return a set of name servers instead:

```
Domain exists:  yes, 4 name servers found
```

Some resolvers may always return the name servers, some may return minimal responses instead. So, this `Domain exists:` line properly returns the number of servers when the name is a domain, but is not reliable when it is a fully-qualified host name.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still confused: If it does not find any nameservers, then how does it find the respective IP Address of the website?

Comment: Nameservers exist, but for the zone. When asked for `docs.example.com`, the response is `no nameservers`, so another query is made for only `example.com`. Then we get name servers, and these are used to get the IP address of everything within that zone.

Comment: By the way, as it was confusing, this indication has been removed in the development version of `dnscrypt-proxy`.

Comment: Ah, wonderful. So there's nothing wrong with my setup except that testing it with a subdomain as query is not really intended.